# What graphics library with custom controls should be selected for ios development?

Tags: ios, ipad, charts, grid, drilldown

I want to find a graphics library for iOS (specifically for iPad), which will have the following features:

> 1. Map
> 2. TreeMap
> 3. Charts (and their asynchronous rendering)
> 4. Time navigator
> 5. Grids
> 6. Drill-Down
> 7. Multiaxial
> 8. Crosshair
> 9. Manual drawing
> 10. Zoom
> 11. Ability to draw shapes or polygons
> 12. Different types of charts (piechart, areachart, barchart, ...)

At the moment I came across a **Shinobicontrols**. Can be experienced developers prompt me which of the following is in the library, and what is not. And may prompt other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [cocoa controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/).

Comment: Oh, thank you! I watched them. I want something more beautiful =)